# WSO2 Instances Configuration

Tags: jdbc, wso2, wso2-api-manager, clustering-key

I'm trying to configure my **Worker-Manager API** instances with the `wso2am-2.0.0`. I have not created databases and made no configurations related to the same. However while running my `bin/wsoserver.sh` throws database exception errors.

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode; SQL statement:
>
> [2016-12-05 23:30:49,842] ERROR - Activator Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot initialize the realm.
>
> Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Database Error - Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode; SQL statement:
>
> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode; SQL statement:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APIM internally uses embedded H2 database. Looks like someone else is using the database. It could be another instance of the same server. Search for such process and kill it. It should solve your problem.